# Where do the plurals of locus come from?

Tags: language-evolution, gender, plural, neuter

The word *locus* is masculine in the singular, but it can be masculine or neuter in the plural.
Geographical places are *loca*, but places in a text are *loci*.
As far as I know, this is the only Latin word with such behaviour.

Do we know where this "double plural" comes from?
Was it always there in the written Latin we know?
Is there a similar situation in related languages (Italic, Greek, PIE, or something) that could shed some light on the problem?

Comment: De Vaan is silent on the plural, but LSJ does mention an inscription (Inscr. ap. Grut. 129, 14) which has a singular *locum*. I suppose it's possible that an old neuter existed that was lost. The inscription is probably a back-formation, though.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As usual, to answer this question we need to step into our comparative linguistics-fueled time machine and go back to Proto-Indo-European times, so we can see what function the ending *-a*, which we know as a neuter plural ending, had in PIE.

In PIE, this ending *-a* (or rather *-(e)h₂) did not form plurals, but [collectives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collective_noun). A collective refers to a group of objects, but is conceptualized as being a single thing, and for grammatical purposes is generally treated as a singular noun; this was probably the case in PIE, and is why in Greek, for example, neuter plural nouns in *-a* still take singular verbs.

PIE collectives seem to have been used most often with neuter nouns -- in fact, neuter nouns don't seem to have had a normal plural (at least not in the nominative/accusative), so the collective form more or less stood in for a plural. This is why in Latin and other languages, *-a* came to be a specifically neuter ending.

But the collective could also be formed from masculine and feminine nouns. *Locus* is one such example: of its two plurals, *locī* continues the PIE plural, while *loca* continues the PIE collective. Lewis and Short describe the difference in meaning as follows: "plur. loci, single places; loca, places connected with each other, a region" -- where the plural vs. collective meanings are clear. *Locus* actually isn't the only such noun in Latin: there's *iocus* "joke", pl. *ioca*, and *carbasus* "sail", pl. *carbasa*. And there's at least one case in which the collective was reinterpreted as a feminine singular: *pila* "ball", which seems to have originally been the collective of *pilus* "hair" (meaning "mass or ball of hair").

(By the way, another heterogeneous noun with a similar story behind it is *frēnum* "rein", pl. *frēnī*. In this case the Latin masculine plural ending continues what was in PIE terms not a plural at all, but a neuter dual.)

Comment: One little question: Does the difference between the origins of *loci* and *loca* explain the difference in meanings in Latin? Or is it just coincidental that some meanings are plural and some collective?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta, there's probably more to it than this, but L&S describes the difference in meaning as follows: "plur. loci, single places; loca, places connected with each other, a region" -- where the plural vs. collective meanings are clear.

Comment: @TKR, does this mean that if I'm talking about places *unconnected* with each other ("He has friends in many places") the plural is *loci*?

Comment: @JoelDerfner, L&S seem to imply such a difference, but I don't know whether usage bears this out.