# Remnants of the dual number

Tags: language-evolution, declension, dual

To my understanding, Latin doesn't have a dual number at all. The adjectives *duo* "two" and *ambō* "both" have some special forms derived from the PIE dual (-*ō*, -*ābus*, -*ōbus*), but are considered irregular rather than part of any real pattern.

However, from an answer to [an unrelated question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/2132/where-do-the-plurals-of-locus-come-from):

> By the way, another heterogeneous noun with a similar story behind it is *frēnum* "rein", pl. *frēnī*. In this case the Latin masculine plural ending continues what was in PIE terms not a plural at all, but a neuter dual.

This points to another trace of the dual number which I hadn't heard about before.

Are there any other irregularities or fossilized forms in Latin which derive from the dual number in PIE or Proto-Italic?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The -ī of *vīgintī* "20" is originally a dual ending, the same one as in *frēnī* (PIE *-ih₁). This is why the ending of *vīgintī* is different from that of the other tens (*trīgintā* etc.)

Answer (score 9):

According to W.M. Lindsay [The Latin Language: An Historical Account of Latin Sounds, Stems, and Flexions](https://books.google.nl/books?id=zEBHglB7zOIC&pg=PA253&lpg=PA253#v=onepage&q&f=false) (p. 253), *octo* could also be a dual in form, with the sense of 'two sets of four'. He sees a comparison with *ambo* and *duo* because of the ending ō-sound.

I don't get why it would mean 'two sets of four' though.

Comment: If the ō-sound is enough, then *Cicero* must mean "two chickpeas". I hope the sound and eight being an even number were not his only reasons to propose this.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta. IE *oḱtō is the dual of a noun the singular of which survives as Avestan ašti- “span, four-fingers length”, as was pointed out by W.B. Henning, Transactions of the Philological Society 1948, p. 69. (Yes, this brilliant article is exactly one page long).

Answer (score 5):

It looks like a couple of neuter nouns of the fourth declension might have nominative singular forms derived from PIE duals. (Note that the nominative neuter ending *-u* might have been pronounced either as *-ŭ* or *-ū;* it seems that we don't have any clear evidence either way for the quality of the vowel in this context.) A form *-ū* with a long vowel could be explained as deriving from PIE dual **-uh₁*; the dual form is mentioned as a possible source of a Latin form in De Vaan's entries for *genu* "knee" ("PIE *ǵen-u(-h₁ dual), *ǵen-u- (obl.)") and *cornu* "horn" ("If *ū* is original, *cornu* may reflect the nom.acc.dual ending **-uh₁*; especially for *cornū* *'pair of horns' > 'horn'").

Comment: This is interesting. I never realised how two of the most common -u nouns normally grow in pairs! And I've always found the -u ending odd (although I might have thought of a dropped -d à la *illud, istud*).

Comment: Cf. dative *cornū* (I think this exists in addition to *cornui*?).

Comment: @Cerberus: I'm not really sure about the etymology or frequency of dative -ū, but it apparently shows up on all kinds of fourth-declension nouns, not just neuters: [How did the fourth declension neuter dative singular become different from the non-neuter ending?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/14059/how-did-the-fourth-declension-neuter-dative-singular-become-different-from-the-n/14110#14110)

Comment: Oh, had forgotten all about that question! It seems I had already voted for your answer there as well.

Comment: Weiss convincingly has the neuter athematic dual as *\*-ih₁* instead, but suggests the *-ū* in the fourth declension neuter nominative is due to the neuter *plural* ending *\*-h₂* and terminal laryngeal loss in pausa later creating long/short variation there. This created ambiguity that was resolved by the singular always being unetymologically long and the plural getting a new ending *-ua* analogous with the other declensions.