# When to use ae vs a for plurals?

Tags: word-comparison, plural

I'm reading **Familia Romana** book and encountered these 2 sentences.

> Corsica et Sardinia **insulae magnae** sunt.

And

> Brundisium et Sparta **oppida magna** sunt.

Why does the *ae* changes to *a* and vice versa?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Latin, nouns belong to different groups, which are called declensions. The word *insula* is of the first declension, whereas the word *oppidum* is of the second declension. Each declension has its own endings. In addition, *oppidum* is neuter.

Neuter words of the second declension have a singular ending *-um*, plural -*a*; words of the first declension have a singular ending on *-a*, and a plural on *-ae*. That's why it is one *oppidum*, two *oppida*; but one *insula*, two *insulae*.

By the way, the fact that both *oppida* (plural) and *insula* (singular) end on *-a* is best considered coincidental in the present context.

Comment: Is there a context in which the shared -a is more than coincidental?

Comment: @BThompson Interesting question! I am far from well-informed about this, someone else will be able to provide better references.... but I found discussion in this thread: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/neuter-plural-feminine-singular-ie-languages.2650663/ and in this article: Rovai, F. (2012). Between Feminine Singular and Neuter Plural: Re-Analysis Patterns. Transactions of the Philological Society, 110(1), 94–121. https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1111/j.1467-968X.2012.01286.x

Comment: @BThompson The answer to this question https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/2132/where-do-the-plurals-of-locus-come-from?rq=1 by TKR also gives a relevant example relating Latin _pilus_ "hair" and _pila_ "ball".

Comment: @BThompson: I think the neuter plural and feminine -a are thought to have been related in Proto-Indo-European, the neuter -a being originally an abstract collective suffix. I'm not sure how well established this theory is.

Comment: Interesting, thank you both!